# List index out of range al hacer scraping

Tags: python, scraping

Estoy intentado realizar un scraping en la página de wikipedia para sacar de una tabla la información sobre los juegos olímpicos.
El tema que en una parte me sale error en el index y no estoy pudiendo solucionar.

```py
import bs4 as bs #-------------> libreria 
import requests #-------------> libreria 
import pandas as pd #-------------> libreria 
from tqdm import tqdm
#def olympic_game ():

response = requests.get ('https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Medallas_ol%C3%ADmpicas')
    
#response = requests.get(web)
#print(response.text)
content = response.text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

table = soup.find ('table', {'class' : 'wikitable'})

Disciplinas = []
Años = []
Medallas = []
Deportistas = []

for medal in tqdm (table.findAll('tr')[1:]):
    Disciplina = medal.findAll('td')[2].text #---------> indice de la informacion que quiero sacar de la pagina
    Año = medal.findAll('td')[3].text #---------> indice de la informacion que quiero sacar de la pagina
    Medalla = medal.findAll('td')[8].text #---------> indice de la informacion que quiero sacar de la pagina
    Deportista = medal.findAll('td')[9].text #---------> indice de la informacion que quiero sacar de la pagina

    Disciplinas.append(Disciplina)
    Años.append(Año)
    Medallas.append(Medalla)
    Deportistas.append(Deportista)
```

> line 30, in 
> year_founded = row.findAll('td')[8].text
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Lo que estás mostrando como error no aparece en el código que estás proporcionando (`year_founded = row.findAll('td')[8].text`). Recuerda proporcionar un [repro].

Comment: Es cualquier error de tipo ,IndexError: list index out of range. Verifica que el selector que se está usando sea el correcto. Algunas veces el comportamiento del sitio no es el mismo cuando se usa el navegador a cuando se usa beautifulsoap o scrapy . Intenta darle un print Al valor que hay en ese selector